Why is the trace distance between two density matrices not always $0$?
If $|A|_{tr}=Tr(\sqrt{A^\dagger A})$ then surely
$$
|\rho_1-\rho_2|_{tr}=Tr(\sqrt{(\rho_1-\rho_2)^\dagger (\rho_1-\rho_2)})
$$
$$
=Tr(\sqrt{(\rho_1^\dagger -\rho_2^\dagger)(\rho_1-\rho_2)})
$$
$$
=Tr(\sqrt{(\rho_1 -\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_2)})
$$
$$
=Tr(\rho_1 -\rho_2)=Tr(\rho_1)-Tr(\rho_2)=1-1=0?
$$

The problem in your analysis is the fourth equality: unless $\rho_1 - \rho_2$ is zero it will not be positive semidefinite, so it will not be the case that $\sqrt{(\rho_1 - \rho_2)(\rho_1 - \rho_2)} = \rho_1 - \rho_2$. Rather, to get this matrix you can replace each eigenvalue of $\rho_1 - \rho_2$ by its absolute value (leaving the eigenvectors alone).
